# How do I run an asynchronous 'find' in a loop while incrementing the find parameter so I can generate unique custom id's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose/mongodb and I am trying to do some sort of error handling with my document save.

I am trying to create a stub id to store into the db for easier data retrieval later on (and also to put into the url bar so people can send links to my website to that particular page more easily -- like jsfiddle or codepen).

Basically I want to search for a document with a page_id and if it exists, I want to regenerate that page_id and search until it gets to one that's unused like this:

```
while(!done){
    Model.findOne({'page_id': some_hex}, function (err, doc) {
        if(doc){
            some_hex = generate_hex();
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    });
}
model.page_id = some_hex;
model.save();
```

However, since mongoose is asynchronous, the while loop will pretty much run indefinitely while the find works in the background until it finds something. This will kill the resources on the server.

I'm looking for an efficient way to retry save() when it fails (with a change to page_id). Or to try and find an unused page_id. I have page_id marked as unique:true in my schema.

Comment: Can't you generate an id that's pretty much guaranteed to be unique to begin with? [`unik`](https://github.com/ricardobeat/unik), [`flocon`](https://github.com/Yosee/flocon), [`ObjectId`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_objectid_ObjectId)

Comment: The reason for the stub is so people can grab that particular page if they plug it into the URL. It would be hard to remember the ObjectId() string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrying should be performed asynchronously:

```
var tryToSave = function(doc, callback) {
  var instance     = new Model(doc);
  instance.page_id = generate_hex();
  instance.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
      if (err.code === 11000) { // 'duplicate key error'
        // retry
        return tryToSave(doc, callback);
      } else {
        // another error
        return callback(err);
      }
    }
    // it worked!
    callback(null, instance);
  });
};

// And somewhere else:
tryToSave(doc, function(err, instance) {
  if (err) ...; // handle errors
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The key was to do recursion asynchronously using the 'return tryToSave()' on error statement.